# How to generate random 0s and 1s but with 80-20 probability of their occurence in C?

Tags: c, arrays, random

Trying to create a program which generates two random numbers(0 & 1) and stores them in an array and prints them, which i have done successfully, problem is that i need the number 1 to be generated with an 80% probability and the number 0 with a 20% probability.

Already done populating the array with random 1s and 0s with `rand()%10`
as the random number generated is between 0-10 the logic i used is that if the random number is greater than 5 ,store it in the array as '1' and if less than 5 ,store in the array as '0'

```
for(i=0;i<=n_gen;i++)               // for allele array
{
     randallele[i]=rand()%10 +1;
     if(randallele[i]>=5)
     {
         randallele[i]=1;
     }
     else
     {
         randallele[i]=0;
     }

}
for(i=0;i<=n_gen;i++)           //prints allele array
{
    printf("Printing the alleles:    %d\n", randallele[i]);
}
```

I expect the output to be generated along with their probabilities(80% for '1' and 20% for '0') rather than directly storing random 1s and 0s

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because

> ```
> randallele[i]=rand()%10 +1;
> ```

get a number between 1 and 10, doing

> ```
> if(randallele[i]>=5)
> {
>     randallele[i]=1;
> }
> else
> {
>     randallele[i]=0;
> }
> ```

you have 5..10 = 6 possibilities to get 1 and 0..4 = 5 to have 0

To have 80% 1s and 20% 0s you just need to change to have :

```
 if(randallele[i]>=3)
 {
     randallele[i]=1;
 }
 else
 {
     randallele[i]=0;
 }
```

because 3..10 = 8 possibilities and 1..2 only 2

A shorter way to have the same result is just to have :

```
randallele[i]=rand()%10 +1;
randallele[i] = (randallele[i]>=3);
```

so finally

```
randallele[i] = ((rand()%10) >= 2);
```

---

Little program to test :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n[2] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i != 100000; i++)
    n[((rand()%10) >= 2)] += 1;

  printf("%d %d => %g%% %g%%\n",
         n[0], n[1], round(n[0] / 1000.0), round(n[1] / 1000.0));

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
20202 79798 => 20% 80%
```

Note : to not have all the time the same result a simple way is to do `srand(time(0));` before to use `rand()`

Comment: thank you so much! your answer was so well explained and neat! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Harvindersingh in theory one has to consider RAND_MAX like Sami Hult says, but you just look at 10 possible values so the error is infinitesimally

Comment: @bruno In this particular case I think the approach above works well, the error is very small. I just wanted to present a solution that works with any percentage :)

Comment: @SamiHult you was 100% (not just 80% ^^) right to do, this is why I upvoted your answer

Comment: @Harvindersingh I don't know what you did, I edited my answer to show a test, it gives 20% 0 and 80% 1. Note that `rand` has its limits, it cannot be 100% random

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a version that you might adapt to whatever output format you need:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int uniform_5(void)
/* Returns 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 with uniform probability.  Call srand() first.
 */
{
  /* Rerolling if we roll below the remainder of RAND_MAX/5 eliminates a
   * slight bias caused by RAND_MAX not being evenly divisible by 5, and
   * samples x from a uniform distribution.
   */ 
  const int x = rand();
  return (x < RAND_MAX % 5) ? uniform_5() : x % 5;
}

bool* fill_bernoulli_80( const ptrdiff_t n, bool output[n] )
/* Fills the output array with n boolean values sampled from a Bernoulli
 * distribution with p = 0.8.
 *
 * Call srand() first.
 */
{
  for ( ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    output[i] = uniform_5() < 4;
  }

  return output;
}

#define NSAMPLES 10000000

int main(void)
{
  static bool samples[NSAMPLES];
  const unsigned random_seed =
    (unsigned)time(NULL)*CLOCKS_PER_SEC + (unsigned)clock();

  srand(random_seed);

  fill_bernoulli_80( NSAMPLES, samples );

  size_t ones = 0;

  for ( ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < NSAMPLES; ++i )
    ones += samples[i];

  printf( "p = %.6f.\n", ones/(double)NSAMPLES );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some quirks of mine that are on display here: I prefer to use `ptrdiff_t` for loop indices, because unsigned math can cause logic errors on overflow or underflow that are hard to detect (the infamous `1U < -3`) and `int` might be 32 bits wide for a 64-bit program.

You can see the influence of functional programming on my tail-recursive helper function `uniform_5`.  It’s not a major issue in this case, but if you were using a large number like `RAND_MAX/2 + 2`, you would definitely notice that taking the remainder does not give you a uniform distribution: some numbers would be rolled twice as often as others.  The rerolling algorithm I use corrects for that.

I combine two sources of entropy into the random seed, the wall time and the CPU time, because it is very possible that the program run twice in the same clock second.

The default PRNG is often not great, but you can also easily substitute a different one.

Comment: Finally this is not better than my trivial solution, if I do 10M rands like you I also get typically 0.08001 like you

Comment: @bruno You say “Finally” as if this were an ongoing conversation, but that was your first comment on my answer, and I hadn’t said anything disparaging about yours. Did you mean to reply to someone else?

Comment: I said 'finally' because I first hopped to get a better result with your proposal, but the tests showed the opposite. You are of course free to comment my answer, where is the problem to comment yours ? All of that just shows _rand_ works well. Probably the more the number of tests is small the best your solution is, 10Mo is a lot

Comment: @bruno I was a bit confused if you meant to reply to me. I’m not sure in what sense you mean a “better” answer. We’re both using `rand()` to generate a binomial distribution, whose result is going to vary. To get a “better” answer, increase the number of trials (lowering the standard deviation) and possibly use a better RNG.

Comment: However I still do not see what was 'disparaging' in my remark, and that was not the goal ...

Comment: @bruno Okay. Great. It sounded as if you were replying to someone who’d said that their solution was better than yours. Turns out that wasn’t the case. Just making sure to clarify that I wasn’t saying that.